# How can I "multiply" rows to every row in another table with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to figure out a SQL query that will distribute or assign records from one table to every record of another table. As example below:

## Codes:

- 10000
- 10001
- 10002
- 10003

## Dates:

- 2016-1-1
- 2016-2-1
- 2016-3-1

## Result:

```
Code  | Date
-----------------
10000 | 2016-1-1
10000 | 2016-2-1
10000 | 2016-3-1
10001 | 2016-1-1
10001 | 2016-2-1
10001 | 2016-3-1
10002 | 2016-1-1
10002 | 2016-2-1
10002 | 2016-3-1
10003 | 2016-1-1
10003 | 2016-2-1
10003 | 2016-3-1
```

Can I construct this join in TSQL?

Comment: Yes, its called CROSS APPLY

Comment: TQ @dfundako :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.codes, d.[date]
FROM codes c CROSS JOIN dates d;
```

Comment: Yes, I use this CROSS JOIN and it works as expected now, TQ @DVT !

Comment: sorry, can't upvote this as my 'points' not enough yet, will back here when time come...TQ also for those proposed similar answer (like John)!

Comment: @YongS. That's fine. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @YongS. I'll UpVote for you.  DVT beat me by 3 seconds :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnCappelletti ! Wish everyone have good weekend and coming holiday (if any) :)